# How To Use \n In a TextBox

Tags: c#, string, newline

I'm developing a program that I'm using a string(`generatedCode`) that contains some `\n` to enter a new-line at the textBox that I'm using it(`textBox1.Text = generatedCode`), but when I'm running the program, instead of breaking that line I'm seeing a square.

Remember that I've set the `Multiline` value of the textBox to `True`.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Replace \n with \r\n - that's how Windows controls represent newlines (but see note at bottom):

```
textBox1.Text = generatedCode.Replace("\n", "\r\n");
```

or

```
textBox1.Text = generatedCode.Replace("\n", Environment.NewLine);
```

Note: As discussed in comments, you *may* want to use `Environment.NewLine`. It's unclear though - it's not well-defined what line separator Windows Forms controls should use when they're not running on Windows. Should they use the platform default, or the Windows one (as it's a port of a Windows GUI control)? One of the examples in MSDN *does* use `Environment.NewLine`, but I've seen horribly wrong examples in MSDN before now, and the documentation just doesn't state which is should be.

In an ideal world, we'd just have one line separator - and even in a second best world, every situation would clearly define which line separator it was expecting...

Comment: Basically the same thing, but it's probably safer to use Environment.NewLine instead of \r\n, I think.

Comment: Hmm, question - ought "\r\n" be System.Environment.NewLine? I appreciate that they're the same (ish), its more of a sort of coding standardy type question

Comment: Given that ".NET" does not imply "Windows," I would strongly concur with using `System.Environment.NewLine`.

Comment: That entirely depends on what other platforms decide to do for Windows Forms controls. Given that they're *Windows* Forms controls, they may well copy the use of "\r\n". To be honest, it feels like Mono is stuck between a rock and a hard place on this one. I would definitely use `Environment.NewLine` for writing a text file for example, but I'm not so sure for WinForms GUIs. Caveat: I don't actually know what Mono does with this on Linux.

Answer (score 10):

since using \n is easier on the eyes (especailly when formatting), and also sometimes you don't control how the source string is constructed - I find best practice is to use:
`TextBox1.Text = str.Replace("\r\n", "\n").Replace("\n", Environment.NewLine);`

Comment: s = s.Replace("\r", "").Replace("\n", Environment.NewLine);

Comment: @SashaBond Much better IMO. Eliminates the edge case of a \r being present on its own whilst also neatly handling \n

Comment: that's one old thread... anyway - \n and \r\n exist and mix everywhere... if there is just \r for some reason - it might be deliberate as no system I know of uses just carriage return to represent a newline. I would leave isolated '\r's in their places unless I have context and know they might exist and that they do represent a newline.

Answer (score 6):

Usually `\r\n` gets me a newline in a textbox. Try replacing your `\n` with `\r\n` just be careful you don't have a mix of `\r\n` and `\n`

Comment: Good point!  just be sure do textBox1.Text = generatedCode.Replace("\r\n", "\n"); to get any existing then do the textBox1.Text = generatedCode.Replace("\n", "\r\n"); Winform still rocks!

Answer (score 4):

Add a carriage return (\r) and it should work:

```
TextBox1.Text = "First line\r\nSecond line";
```