# How to Exit a Method without Exiting the Program?

Tags: c#, function, methods, return, exit

I am still pretty new to C# and am having a difficult time getting used to it compared to C/CPP.

How do you exit a function on C# without exiting the program like this function would?

```
if (textBox1.Text == "" || textBox1.Text == String.Empty || textBox1.TextLength == 0)
    textBox3.Text += "[-] Listbox is Empty!!!!\r\n";
System.Environment.Exit(0);
```

This will not allow return types and if left alone it will keep going on through the function unstopped. Which is undesirable.

Comment: BTW, they're called "methods", not "functions" these days.

Comment: @John I've been programming in C# and other OOP languages for a good time now and I still call them functions. (and I'm only 19!)

Comment: @Earlz: maybe it's just me, but I find that most people who still say "function", or "subroutine" don't know OO. Therefore, hearing someone say "function" gives me the impression they don't know OO.

Comment: Every method is a function, and is also a subroutine (but not every function or subroutine is a method). In any case, in my favorite language it's called "member functions", and that's the way I likes them! ;)

Comment: @John, a method, to me, implies operating on an instance. A function operates on its arguments, regardless of whether or not it is static. A method is a sub-case of functions that operate on an instance, where there the instance is the first argument (implied or explicit, depending on your language).

Comment: @Nathan: I prefer "instance method" and "static method" or "class method". Functions are a non-OO concept, and don't refer to the concept of a class.

Comment: To most the difference between "method" and "function" is like the difference between "armor" and "armour" or "color" and "colour". It depends on how you look at it.

Comment: Methods can be distinguished from functions with the rule that they require the runtime type of an argument or arguments (multi-methods) to determine how dispatch them.  One could also say a method is encapsulated by a class or object, which would accommodate static methods and javascript prototypes, but might exclude multi-methods.   The first would allow "function" to be used for "statically dispatched" execution bits; the second would only allow for "bare" execution bits (not possible in Java, but certainly so in c# and javascript, c++ and c).

Answer (score 170, accepted):

There are two ways to exit a method early (without quitting the program):

- Use the [`return`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1h3swy84.aspx) keyword.
- Throw an exception.

Exceptions should only be used for exceptional circumstances - when the method cannot continue and it cannot return a reasonable value that would make sense to the caller. Usually though you should just return when you are done.

If your method returns void then you can write return without a value:

```
return;
```

---

Specifically about your code:

- There is no need to write the same test three times. All those conditions are equivalent.
- You should also use curly braces when you write an if statement so that it is clear which statements are inside the body of the if statement:

  ```
  if (textBox1.Text == String.Empty)
  {
      textBox3.Text += "[-] Listbox is Empty!!!!\r\n";
  }
  return; // Are you sure you want the return to be here??
  ```
- If you are using .NET 4 there is a useful method that depending on your requirements you might want to consider using here: [String.IsNullOrWhitespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace.aspx).
- You [might](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1751371/how-to-use-n-in-a-textbox) want to use [`Environment.Newline`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline.aspx) instead of `"\r\n"`.
- You might want to consider another way to display invalid input other than writing messages to a text box.

Comment: It was so simple! Just return without a value! Thanks a lot! I was returning with 0. =)

Comment: Or `string.IsNullOrEmpty` (pre .Net 4 shout-out - which, of course does not detect whitespace-only strings). Sadly, not all of us can use 4.0, yet.

Comment: "return" doesn't work if you're in a nested piece of code, such as in a "catch".

Answer (score 9):

In addition to Mark's answer, you also need to be aware of scope, which (as in C/C++) is specified using braces. So:

```
if (textBox1.Text == "" || textBox1.Text == String.Empty || textBox1.TextLength == 0)
    textBox3.Text += "[-] Listbox is Empty!!!!\r\n";
return;
```

will always return at that point. However:

```
if (textBox1.Text == "" || textBox1.Text == String.Empty || textBox1.TextLength == 0)
{
    textBox3.Text += "[-] Listbox is Empty!!!!\r\n";
    return;
}
```

will only return if it goes into that `if` statement.

Answer (score 3):

I would use `return null;` to indicate that there is no data to be returned

Answer (score 1):

The basic problem here is that you are mistaking `System.Environment.Exit` for `return`.

Answer (score 0):

If the function is a void, ending the function will `return`. Otherwise, you need to do an explicit `return someValue`. As Mark mentioned, you can also `throw` an exception.

Comment: Throwing an exception in this case is not best practice

Answer (score 0):

@John, Earlz and Nathan. The way I learned it at uni is: functions return values, methods don't. In some languages the syntax is/was actually different. Example (no specific language):

```
Method SetY(int y) ...
Function CalculateY(int x) As Integer ...
```

Most languages now use the same syntax for both versions, using void as a return type to say there actually isn't a return type. I assume it's because the syntax is more consistent and easier to change from method to function, and vice versa.