# Is there any way to break out of a function that returns void?

Tags: c#, oop

I have a function that sets a draw-state for a specific tile given another tile. The tile that's draw state is going to change compares tiles that are surrounding it and then updates accordingly. I'll try to illustrate that below

```
[b] [b] [a]
[b] [a] [a]
[a] [a] [a]  where a = sand && b = water
```

when a detects that b is bordering it, it must update its draw-state. So I have a function that works for an upper case, lower case, left case, and right case. I now need to modify that function so it can handle a left-right case, upper-right case, lower-right case, etc. etc. Here is my function

```
public override void CompareBorderingTiles(Tile T)
    {
        if (T is Water)
        {
            float leftBound = location.X - (Tile.TileWidth * Tile.TileScale);
            float rightBound = location.X + (Tile.TileWidth * Tile.TileScale);
            float upperBound = location.Y - (Tile.TileHieght * Tile.TileScale);
            float bottomBound = location.Y + (Tile.TileHieght * Tile.TileScale);
            if (T.GridLocation.X == leftBound)
            {
                drawstate = DrawState.Left;
            }
            if (T.GridLocation.X == rightBound)
                drawstate = DrawState.Right;
            if (T.GridLocation.Y == upperBound)
                drawstate = DrawState.Upper;
            if (T.GridLocation.Y == bottomBound)
                drawstate = DrawState.Lower; 
        }

        base.CompareBorderingTiles(T);
    }
```

It should be pretty explanatory as to why i'd want to break out of this function, or maybe not. Basically I have an enum which tells me what my draw-state is (drawstate is the enum).
Can anybody tell me if I can set that correct draw state and then get out of my function?

Comment: you mean you want to stop your function? if it's true you can use `return;` for it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Exit a Method without Exiting the Program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314305/how-to-exit-a-method-without-exiting-the-program)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just use a return statement where you want to end:

```
return;
```

So, in your code you could do:

```
public override void CompareBorderingTiles(Tile T)
{
    if (T is Water)
    {
        float leftBound = location.X - (Tile.TileWidth * Tile.TileScale);
        float rightBound = location.X + (Tile.TileWidth * Tile.TileScale);
        float upperBound = location.Y - (Tile.TileHieght * Tile.TileScale);
        float bottomBound = location.Y + (Tile.TileHieght * Tile.TileScale);
        if (T.GridLocation.X == leftBound)
        {
            drawstate = DrawState.Left;
            return;
        }
        if (T.GridLocation.X == rightBound)
        {
            drawstate = DrawState.Right;
            return;
        }
        if (T.GridLocation.Y == upperBound)
        {
            drawstate = DrawState.Upper;
            return;
        }
        if (T.GridLocation.Y == bottomBound)
        {
            drawstate = DrawState.Lower; 
            return;
        }
    }

    base.CompareBorderingTiles(T);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Just use `return;` on its own, this will immediately "return" from the function.

On reflection though do you really need to return?

```
   if (T.GridLocation.X == leftBound)
    {
        drawstate = DrawState.Left;
    }
    else if (T.GridLocation.X == rightBound)
    {
        drawstate = DrawState.Right;
    }

    else if (T.GridLocation.Y == upperBound)
    {
        drawstate = DrawState.Upper;
    }
    else if (T.GridLocation.Y == bottomBound)
    {
        drawstate = DrawState.Lower; 
    }
```

That should make the code easier to maintain in the future.

Comment: Yes I believe that I should because I'm going to need to set an upper-left state, lower-left state etc based on where the tile is on my grid.

Comment: Yes but you only set one variable `drawstate` to any one of the 4 states. So really you don't need to return.  All you want to do is do your checks set `drawstate` and the function will return by itself

Answer (score 7):

You can exit a function with `return`.

Comment: ah I didn't know you could use the return keyword on it's own, I feel like an idiot now, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `return;` at any point in the function and it will leave the function there and then. Using return would mean your base function would **not** be called. If you require the base function to be called use `else if` then when you're condition is fulfilled it won't check the remaining if statements:

```
public override void CompareBorderingTiles(Tile T)
    {
        if (T is Water)
        {
            float leftBound = location.X - (Tile.TileWidth * Tile.TileScale);
            float rightBound = location.X + (Tile.TileWidth * Tile.TileScale);
            float upperBound = location.Y - (Tile.TileHieght * Tile.TileScale);
            float bottomBound = location.Y + (Tile.TileHieght * Tile.TileScale);
            if (T.GridLocation.X == leftBound)
            {
                drawstate = DrawState.Left;
            }
            else if (T.GridLocation.X == rightBound)
                drawstate = DrawState.Right;
            else if (T.GridLocation.Y == upperBound)
                drawstate = DrawState.Upper;
            else if (T.GridLocation.Y == bottomBound)
                drawstate = DrawState.Lower; 
        }

        base.CompareBorderingTiles(T);
    }
```

Comment: This - even if you don't want to call the `base` function, just wrap it in an else. These `else if`s are much easier to follow than lots of `return`s dotted about.

Answer (score 0):

use `return;`
the function will return as a void