# proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd() doesn't split the lines

Tags: c#, cmd, testim.io

Can you please help me with understanding where is my mistake by running the code?
I expect to revive output string from CMD shell from C# built app and im getting all in one string without separating lines.
I'm running CLI for automated testing.
See attached code and pictures.
Thank you in Advance.
s string:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.16299.431]
(c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\evgen\source\repos\testim_ex1\testim_ex1\bin\Debug>testim --token "98IQGMuu1jTaBp3HvIMkmsk6tTa2jrS4hUFE247rX9ef0s3FAp" --project "KsfNpLJSbdNlY8czyuwb" --host "ondemand.testim.io" --port 4444 --report-file testim-report.xml --label  "EvgenyShai"
Starting Testim.io CLI
Warning: You are using version 1.16.0, a newer version is available. To update please run npm install (npm install -g @testim/testim-cli)
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Running Project: KsfNpLJSbdNlY8czyuwb Label: [ 'EvgenyShai' ] Branch: master
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Batch execution huueFFGwEk was created
Got batch to run:
     1 : Search show in eztv (3gHheApBMO)
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
W:1 Test Search show in eztv started (3gHheApBMO) url: https://app.testim.io/#/project/KsfNpLJSbdNlY8czyuwb/branch/master/test/3gHheApBMO?result-id=2ox8E7Emku
W:1 Get browser Search show in eztv
W:1 Wait for test start
W:1 Wait for test complete
W:1 Test Search show in eztv finished status: PASSED (3gHheApBMO) duration: 0:0:0:17.955
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Execution completed id: huueFFGwEk Label: [ 'EvgenyShai' ] Duration: 0:0:0:32.945 PASSED: 1 FAILED: 0
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
JUnit XML file saved to testim-report.xml
```

C:\Users\evgen\source\repos\testim_ex1\testim_ex1\bin\Debug>

```
private void B_RunTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd");
    psi.UseShellExecute = false;
    psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    psi.RedirectStandardError = true;
    psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
    psi.RedirectStandardInput = true;

    var proc = Process.Start(psi);
    t = TB_CLIstring.Text.ToUpper();

    if (t == "CLS")
    {
       proc.StandardInput.WriteLine(TB_CLIstring.Text);
       proc.StandardInput.Flush();
       proc.StandardInput.Close();
       TB_CMD_Output.Text = "";
    }
    else
    {

        proc.StandardInput.WriteLine(TB_CLIstring.Text);
        proc.StandardInput.Flush();
        proc.StandardInput.Close();

        s = proc.StandardError.ReadToEnd() + proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

        TB_CMD_Output.Text = s;
    }
}
```

How it should be:

[image: How it should be]

---

How it is:

[image: How it is]

Comment: can you add the escaped string from `s = proc.StandardError.ReadToEnd() + proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();` to your question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How To Use \n In a TextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1751371/how-to-use-n-in-a-textbox)

Comment: Is this still an issue you need help with?