# How to use New line in textbox.text in c#

Tags: c#

How to add new line of data to TextBox, like for example:

```
for(int i = 0;i <= 10;i++) { textbox.text = textbox.text + i what i **write here to new line** }
```

Why does someone who uses “n\” in textbox codes not post a new line? What is the reason? I searched for my hobby and did not know anything about it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1751371/how-to-use-n-in-a-textbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If You use it for Unity Editor,
You Should Configure Rich Text in Text, Inspector.
[image]
When Rich Text's Toggle will enable, it will work.
Otherwise it doesn't work.

Comment: No I am use visual studio

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 4):

You should try `Environment.NewLine`, just like this:

```cs
string myString = "This is the first line." + Environment.NewLine + "This is the second line.";
```